# How can I let the Open Source community know about a project that may help them?

Tags: marketing, open-source

I created a web app/service that I think can really help a lot of open source projects by giving them a free Q&A site.

How can I let "them" (the projects creators) know that the service exists without been spam?

I contacted a couple of open source communities in my country, but I want to have a bigger impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too open ended to be put here, as stated in the [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) :

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

That being said, there is no easy, unequivocal answer to your question.

Making something well known to a large group of people is difficult and takes time. The most important thing you should focus on is making sure that your service is well built because otherwise, even if you do manage to somehow get all the attention in the world, people still won't use your service. As the old saying goes: "If you make it, they will come."

Apart from that, the best way to let the community know that your service exists is to just have it out there, get in contact with news sites that deal with the particular market you are aiming at and you can even pay for advertising on something like [Google Adwords](http://www.adwords.google.com) if you are so inclined.